# XML Import to WordPress Database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

What is the best way to keep IDs unique when importing existing IDs into a database that may cause conflicts? E.g:

Example XML to import into the WordPress taxonomy database;

```
<CategoryData>
<Category>
    <id>1</id>
    <parent_id>0</parent_id>
    <name>maincategory1</name>
    <desc>the main 1</desc>
    <keyword />
    <url />
    <image_location>1.jpg</image_location>
    <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
</Category>
<Category>
    <id>2</id>
    <parent_id>0</parent_id>
    <name>maincategory2</name>
    <desc>the main number 2</desc>
    <keyword />
    <url />
    <image_location>2.jpg</image_location>
    <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
</Category>
</CategoryData>
```

However, the WordPress database already has IDs 1-20 (for example) used up by typical post categories for news, etc. If I keep receiving XML like this to update/add to my WooCommerce categories, how can I allow both the WordPress post categories, and XML WooCommerce shop categories to co-exist without overwriting the existing IDs?

I'm all out of ideas except for asking the provider of the XML to change his IDs to begin at 100 or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the XML-id as a custom-meta-field. You would have to check if there is any term with a specific xml-id and if not, you create a new term. Otherwise you can update the existing one.

Add meta fields to wp-terms: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta